# No owin.Environment item was found in the context - only on server

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin

I'm getting this error: `No owin.Environment item was found in the context`

I've seen a zillion posts telling me that I need `<appSettings> <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[AssemblyName].Startup, [AssemblyName]" /> </appSettings>` but that does nothing for me.

I am running Identity 2.0 and all upgraded OWIN components.

Also, this runs fine locally, but when pushed to my VM, I get this error?

Seems like either a setting is off or something else needs to be installed. WebPI says I have .NET 4.5.1 installed.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bah! The server needed to be rebooted. I wasn't prompted to, so I figured I didn't need to. I did. Have I learned nothing from The IT Crowd!? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a OWIN server loaded into you app? Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb is the most common (right now):

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/

Comment: Yep. v2.1. Also, I used the VS 2013 template and it didn't work when I pushed, so I upgraded all the OWIN components and tried again, but still nothing.

Comment: How can I know if I have if?