# ASP.NET MVC: No owin.Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I feel I've got the same problem as [described in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276144/microsoft-owin-host-systemweb-and-still-getting-no-owin-environment-item-was-fou). I 
am working on an ASP.NET MVC web application that runs fine locally. When deployed to our Windows Server 2008 with IIS7, however, I get the following error when trying to log in:

> No owin.Environment item was found in the context.

This is the line that triggers this error:

```
return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
```

I have tried all I could find:

1. Adding  `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="My_App.Startup,My-App"/>` toe the web.config. My Application has a hyphen in its name, but
   that should not be a problem, right?
2. Adding `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>` to the
   web.config.
3. Adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` to the
   web.config.
4. I verified that `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` is installed and in the
   bin-folder.
5. Clearing the ASP.net temporary files.
6. The app pool is set to "integrated"

It's working just fine locally. **What am I missing?**

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232549/no-owin-environment-item-was-found-in-the-context) thread. I have tried the solution from there (see my #1) to no success. Also, I have not changed the namespace.

**Edit**
One solution is to register the OwinHttpHandler explicitly in the web.config but this had some strange side effects (my CSS and JavaScript are not loaded anymore, Status 404?):

```
<handlers>
    <add name="OWIN" path="*" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232549/no-owin-environment-item-was-found-in-the-context

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the solution given there did not work for me - I have already tried it (see my point #1 and #4)

Comment: How is the app pool configured?

Comment: The app pool is set to integrated.

Comment: Make sure the identity worker has full control of the root folder and set the CAS trust level to full

Comment: An old thread I know, but I'm having the same issue - did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

**Naming Convention:** *Katana looks for a class named Startup in namespace matching the assembly name or the global namespace.*

**OwinStartup Attribute:** *This is the approach most developers will take to specify the startup class. The following attribute will set the startup class to the TestStartup class in the StartupDemo namespace.*

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(StartupDemo.TestStartup))]

<appSettings>  
  <add key="owin:appStartup" value="StartupDemo.ProductionStartup" />
</appSettings>
```

The following key, which explicitly specifies the startup class and assembly can also be used:

```
  <add key="owin:appStartup" value="StartupDemo.ProductionStartup, StartupDemo" />


<appSettings>  
  <add key="owin:appStartup" value="ProductionConfiguration" />       
</appSettings>
```

The above markup must be used with the following OwinStartup attribute which specifies a friendly name and causes the ProductionStartup2 class to run.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("ProductionConfiguration", typeof(StartupDemo.ProductionStartup2))]

namespace StartupDemo
{
    public class ProductionStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                string t = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(t + " Production OWIN App");
            });
        }
    }
    public class ProductionStartup2
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                string t = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(t + " 2nd Production OWIN App");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I added Identity to an existing project.  I found that when I added the Identity packages from NuGet I didn't have a Startup.cs at the root of the project.  I added one with the following code and all worked well.

```html
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourProjectName.Startup))]
namespace YourProjectName
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```