# 500 error when trying to register new user on asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am hosting my asp.net web api on a windows server. The Api uses individual authentication. When I try registering a new user, I get the following error (after enabling failed request tracing. An existing user on the DB can login but the api only fails when trying to create a user (register). Any suggestions?

I tried `key=owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"` in my config file

ModuleName

> __DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_f8907279-e4fe-493a-8c69-1c930b7c2600

Notification

```
PRE_EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
```

> HttpStatus 500
>
> HttpReason Internal Server Error
>
> HttpSubStatus 0
>
> ErrorCode The operation completed successfully.  (0x0)
>
> ConfigExceptionInfo

I don't get these errors when hosting on my PC. Also, I have recently installed an ssl certificate and added a domain. Could this be affecting it?

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276144/microsoft-owin-host-systemweb-and-still-getting-no-owin-environment-item-was-fou

Comment: Hi. I tried that fix. Still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging locally, I discovered that my email sending details in my config file were incorrect. My web api sends an email verification link before a user is registered which is why existing users were not effected.

Thanks to all who helped.