# How to get OwinContext from Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, simple-injector

I am trying to set up my Dependency Injection and I am in the need of injecting a `IAuthenticationManager` from ASP.NET Identity to an `OwinContext`.

For this I am from my `Global.asax -> ServiceConfig.Configure()` running:

```
 container.Register(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
```

But when I am running my application I get this message:

> No owin.Environment item was found in the context

Why is this HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext() not available from Global.asax?

*Startup.cs*

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MyApp.Web.Startup))]
namespace Speedop.Web
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

*Startup.Auth.cs*

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager<User, int>, User, int>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie),
                    getUserIdCallback: (id) => (Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
                    )
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168978/do-i-need-a-global-asax-cs-file-at-all-if-im-using-an-owin-startup-cs-class-and).  Mainly, Global.asax is called before Startup.cs

Comment: Hm, I do have 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll' in my directory. I tried moving everything to Startup.cs from my Global.asax after I did ConfigureAuth(...) still the same message comes.

Comment: I just tried creating a whole new sample app and tried getting the OwinContext with the same results. There must be a way :-)

Comment: [Here's a discussion](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/539965) about Owin with Simple Injector. Perhaps that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, I will try when I get home and let you know. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, maybe I should find another solution on how to inject a IAuthenticationManager into my service.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed this with the following:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest(() =>
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null && container.IsVerifying())
    {
        return new OwinContext().Authentication;
    }
    return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

});
```

Seems like the OwnContext is not present at startup, so I'll wait for it and inject it once its present. Please note that the `container.IsVerifying()` is present in `SimpleInjector.Advanced`

Comment: What is this "RegisterPerWebRequest()" ? where do you get it from ?  Unity doesn't seem to have such a method or extention

Comment: Found it. You're using SimpleInjector. ok. Question is how do You register the type. For example, controller needs a repo, that need the IauthManager.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with Castle Windsor?

Comment: In Castle windsor you can do the following:
            container.Register(Component.For<IAuthenticationManager>().UsingFactoryMethod(
                    () =>
                    {
                        if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null)
                        {
                            return new OwinContext().Authentication;
                        }

                        return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

                    }).LifestylePerWebRequest());